# How to update a datetime column with date now but time is minus 2 hour in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I would like to update a data record in Database like an example

Original datetime: 2022-03-21 **08:43:15.609**
Then I wanna update, change the time is back to **120 minutes** ago: 2022-03-21 **06:43:15.609**

Could anyone help me please, I'm new to databases so I'm a bit confused, thank you for taking the time to help me

Comment: `UPDATE table SET dt_column = dt_column - INTERVAL 2 HOUR WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = DATE_SUB('2022-03-21 08:43:15.609',INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET time_col= now()- INTERVAL 2 HOUR WHERE..;